# Missing or insufficient permissions in firebase even after login

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, facebook-login

I use facebook login for my application. when the user is created using Facebook login, the backend code is programmatically converting that user as a `emailVerified` user.

While login `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` gives

```
User(
  displayName: Balaji Venkatraman, 
  email: ****@gmail.com, 
  emailVerified: true,  // note: Email verified is true
  isAnonymous: false, 
  metadata: 
  UserMetadata(
    creationTime: 2021-01-21 16:36:58.098, 
    lastSignInTime: 2021-01-21 16:36:58.099), 
    phoneNumber: null, 
    photoURL: '',
    providerData, [
        UserInfo(
          displayName: Balaji Venkatraman, 
          email: '****@gmail.com', 
          phoneNumber: null, 
          photoURL: '',)
      ], 
    refreshToken: , 
    tenantId: null, 
    uid: sRrazGn8tSWagoD2N3oyCEa92yE2,
  )
```

Here i am able to successfully login and `emailVerfied` flag is also true.But creating collection gives error saying(we have a rule to check the user email verified):

> Write failed at users/sRrazGn8tSWagoD2N3oyCEa92yE2/userAssessment/food: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Here is my rule

```
function signedInOrPublic(){
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != "anonymous" && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
}
match /userAssessment/{category}{
 allow read, write: if signedInOrPublic();
}
```

Comment: You most likely have an issue with your security rules.

Comment: function signedInOrPublic(){
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != "anonymous" && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
}
match /userAssessment/{category}{
a llow read, write: if signedInOrPublic();
}
This is my rule

Comment: did you able to reproduce this issue over an environment without rules?

Comment: No actually i need rules becuase it is a production app.So i cannot test by disabling the rules

Comment: If you try with Firebase emulator or by creating another project (for staging)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't remember exactly how the rules should be written, but you can try to delete one logical expression at the time to isolate the problem, and after that you can google to find the proper way to write it.

Are you sure userId contains the user UID?

Comment: No, we cant do that.It is a production application.Also it prints the UID

Comment: I think you need a second environment. Even if you detect the problem, you shouldn't release the fix directly in the production environment without testing the fix.